# EC2 background tasks and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

Hi I would like to run some background processing task to download stuff, while operating my rails applications on EC2, is that possible ?

Comment: it is possible, ec2 instance is similar as a physical server, you can run rails service, you can also login it via ssh or RDS directly to download stuff.